# pyparsing: Nested countedArray?

Tags: python, pyparsing

This is a snippet of a DSL that I am attempting to parse using pyparsing

I have a string of the format `<keyword> 02 01 30 03 40 20 10`

Where 

`02` is the number of strings

`01` is the length of string1 (in bytes)

`30` is the string1 itself

`03` is the length of string2 (in bytes)

 `40 20 10` is the string2

How do I tokenize this string using pyparsing?

Comment: It's not really an answer to your question because it does not use pyparsing, but why not make use of .split() ?

Comment: @DHandle That's what I am doing after giving up :) Thought it would be nicer learn pyparsing a little better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it's a countedArray of countedArray's? Did you try:

```
from pyparsing import Word,nums,alphas,countedArray

test = "key 02 01 30 03 40 20 10"

integer = Word(nums)

# each string is a countedArray of integers, and the data is a counted array
# of those, so...
lineExpr = Word(alphas)("keyword") + countedArray(countedArray(integer))("data")

# parse the test string, showing the keyworod, and list of lists for the data
print lineExpr.parseString(test).asList()
```

Gives:

```
['key', [['30'], ['40', '20', '10']]]
```

The named results also let you get at the parsed bits by name:

```
result = lineExpr.parseString(test)
print result.keyword
print result.data
```

Gives:

```
key
[[['30'], ['40', '20', '10']]]
```

Comment: Never struck me to use it like this. I was thinking of something like this for a nested array. Thanks for nice answer

Comment: Much of parser development involves thinking kind of inside-out, how the small pieces build up to bigger pieces. When I looked at your post, I saw that the inner strings were counted arrays of integers, and the list of those counted arrays were preceded by the number of strings, so an outer counted array. After that, the parser pretty much wrote itself.

Comment: All of computer science is like that. Isn't it

Comment: Yes, except for the writing itself part.

Comment: I bow to thy articulative prowess.